# Aptana: How to have php files open with web browser by default

Tags: php, browser, aptana, default

As the topic says, how do I get php files to open with the web browser by default when I click run?

Comment: You need a local server perhaps wamp, mamp or lamp, or xampp

Comment: I have xampp installed and I've added it to the web servers under perfs.; however, it still runs php files as php scripts, rather then in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I fount this page while searching for your question. I'm not sure. Try this way.
[Click here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/aptana-studio-3-file-associations/)

Comment: changing the perfs. for php files doesn't do anything, it still runs as a php script when clicking run.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a run configuration for PHP to run as a webpage? `Run > Run configurations`

[image]